# KnockoutJS subscribe to multiple observables with same callback action

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've got a model class in KnockoutJS which has multiple values that I'd like to subscribe to.  Each subscription will perform the same task, like so:

```
function CaseAssignmentZipCode(zipCode, userId, isNew) {
  var self = this;
  self.zipCode = ko.observable(zipCode);
  self.userId = ko.observable(userId);
  self.isNew = isNew;
  self.isUpdated = false;

  self.zipCode.subscribe(function () { self.isUpdated = true; });
  self.userId.subscribe(function () { self.isUpdated = true; });
}
```

Is there a way to combine these two calls to subscribe, so that I can use one subscription to 'watch' both values?

Comment: For those looking for a more elaborate solution the plugin below might be worth considering: https://github.com/ZiadJ/knockoutjs-reactor

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use a computed observable for this purpose.  You just need to make sure that you access the value of each observable in the read function.  Would be something like:

```
ko.computed(function() {
   self.zipCode();
   self.userId();
   self.isUpdated = true;
});
```

So, you get dependencies on the two observables and set your flag.

Also, if you are looking for something like a "dirty" flag, then you might consider something like: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html.  The idea is that you use a computed observable that calls ko.toJS() on an object to unwrap all of its observables.

Comment: I have seen this solution and I'm not that happy with it because the computed isn't really computing anything, so the code is harder to understand.

Comment: Computed observables do not necessarily need to return a value. The dependency tracking mechanism has many uses. Knockout uses computeds to track dependencies in bindings, as an example. Here is a recent post about some of the ways that computeds can be used: http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/02/19/getting-knockout-js-computed-observables/

Comment: @RPNiemeyer - yes, it absolutely works and it's concise.  I'm just reacting to readability.

Comment: nice idea @RPNiemeyer ! but how to make computed not evaluate onLoad but it should evaluate if something like `self.zipCode` is modified later on. i tried modifying zipCode (binded to textbox) but nah computed doesn't seem  to evaluate . check here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27278/

Comment: It's rather unfortunate that an explicit facility wasn't provided for this (e.g. `ko.subscribe([array of observables], callback)`.  The shortcomings of this approach are that it isn't a documented usage and that it relies upon side-effects of the computed function rather than it being the primary purpose of the function.  For this reason, this approach is more difficult to understand.  In the absence of an API specifically for this purpose, this pattern nevertheless provides a valuable facility.

Answer (score 20):

Do you not want to duplicate handler function's body? Extract it to a variable.

```
function CaseAssignmentZipCode(zipCode, userId, isNew) {
  var self = this;
  self.zipCode = ko.observable(zipCode);
  self.userId = ko.observable(userId);
  self.isNew = isNew;
  self.isUpdated = false;

  var handler = function () { self.isUpdated = true; };

  self.zipCode.subscribe(handler);
  self.userId.subscribe(handler);
}
```

Comment: In the past, I've always favored the computed approach. But when I see this, I feel like in those times I might've been drunk with the knockout juice. Having now built many enterprise solutions using knockout, this is my preferred approach.

Comment: One upside to using the computed approach is you can use rate-limiting on the computed for throttling

Answer (score 2):

Improving upon refactoring the function body into a variable, by turning the list of dependencies to track into a loop:

```
function CaseAssignmentZipCode(zipCode, userId, isNew) {
  var self = this;
  self.zipCode = ko.observable(zipCode);
  self.userId = ko.observable(userId);
  self.isNew = isNew;
  self.isUpdated = false;

  var handler = function () { self.isUpdated = true; };

  ko.utils.arrayForEach([self.zipCode, self.userId], function(obs) {
    obs.subscribe(handler);
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create some kind of an extension for this purpose. Simple example:

```
function subscribeMany(callback, observables) {    
    for (var i = 0; i < observables.length; i++) {
        observables[i].subscribe(callback);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var name = ko.observable();
var email = ko.observable();

var callback = function(value) {
    console.log(value);
};

subscribeMany(callback, [name, email]);

name('test 1')
email('test 2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript version made for executing the same call back on any Observable in a list of Observables.

This solution works for the types:

1. `KnockoutObservableArray<KnockoutObservable<T>>`
2. `KnockoutObservable<KnockoutObservable<T>[]>`
3. `KnockoutObservable<T>[]`

Benefits of this approach:

1. If an Observable gets added to your `KnockoutObservableArray` then the change will be detected and the subscribe function will be added to that Observable as well.
2. The same solution can be used for many different types and the types are handled for you.

   ```
   function subscribeMany<T>(
       observables: KnockoutObservableArray<KnockoutObservable<T>> | KnockoutObservable<KnockoutObservable<T>[]> | KnockoutObservable<T>[],
       callback: (v: T) => void
       ): KnockoutObservableArray<KnockoutObservable<T>> | KnockoutObservable<KnockoutObservable<T>[]> | KnockoutObservable<T>[] {

       function _subscribeMany<T>(
           observables: KnockoutObservableArray<KnockoutObservable<T>> | KnockoutObservable<KnockoutObservable<T>[]> | KnockoutObservable<T>[],
           callback: (v: T) => void): void {

           if (_isObservableArray<T>(observables)) {
               _subcribeAndRun(observables, (array) => {
                   array.forEach((observable) => {
                       observable.subscribe(callback);
                   });
               });
           }
           else {
               ko.unwrap(observables).forEach((observable) => {
                   observable.subscribe(callback);
               });
           }
       }

       function _isObservableArray<T>(observables: KnockoutObservableArray<KnockoutObservable<T>> | KnockoutObservable<KnockoutObservable<T>[]> | KnockoutObservable<T>[]): observables is KnockoutObservableArray<KnockoutObservable<T>> | KnockoutObservable<KnockoutObservable<T>[]> {
           return "subscribe" in observables;
       }

       function _subcribeAndRun<T>(o: KnockoutObservable<T>, callback: (v: T) => void): KnockoutObservable<T> {
           o.subscribe(callback);
           callback(o());

           return o;
       }

       _subscribeMany<T>(observables, callback);
       return observables;
   }
   ```