# Setting callback function for every observable for every ViewModel in knockout

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I am looking for a way to setup a callback function which will be invoked after every observable in every ViewModel.

Something similar to [ajaxSend](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) and [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) with jquery where a function will be called after each ajax call.

After looking for something like this in knockout, I found only few things: e[xplicitly subscribing to observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) and using [computed observables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9278782/1090562). Neither of these things solves my problem, because I have a lot of ViewModels and therefore using this way I will be forced duplicate code in every ViewModel.

Is there a way in knockout to subscribe to the change of any observable in any model?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do something like this:

1) Create function, that you want to be called when any observable in any viewModel changed (first parameter - value, second - event type, the same as in `subscribe` function third parameter):

```
function extendNotification(valueToNotify, event) {
    if (event != "beforeChange") {
        console.log("extend notification: " + valueToNotify);
    }
};
```

2) Create helper wrapper:

```
function beforeWrapper(fnBefore, fnOriginal) {
    return function () {
        fnBefore.apply(this, arguments);
        return fnOriginal.apply(this, arguments);
    };
};
```

3) And wrap `ko.subscribable.fn.notifySubscribers` function with your extender:

```
ko.subscribable.fn.notifySubscribers =
    beforeWrapper(extendNotification, ko.subscribable.fn.notifySubscribers);
```

May be it is not the best solution for your problem, but you could modify it if you want.
Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ivan_Srb/MxU2a/2/).