# In a program using knockout.js with multiple ViewModels, how can know one specific view model is changed by change in the property?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, knockout.js

I am using asp.net mvc with knockout for data binding.
I have three view models which are as below:

```
function PersonViewModel() {
        this.firstName = ko.observable("@Model.FirstName");
        this.lastName = ko.observable("@Model.LastName");
    }
    function ContactViewModel() {
        this.homePhone = ko.observable("@Model.HomePhone");
        this.mobile = ko.observable("@Model.Mobile");
    }

    function AddressViewModel() {
        this.city = ko.observable("@Model.City");
        this.street = ko.observable("@Model.Street");
    }

 var pvm = new PersonViewModel();
    var avm = new AddressViewModel();
    var cvm = new ContactViewModel();
    var pNode = $("#personal-information").get(0);
    var aNode = $("#address-information").get(0);
    var cNode = $("#contact-information").get(0);
    ko.applyBindings(pvm, pNode);
    ko.applyBindings(avm, aNode);
    ko.applyBindings(cvm, cNode);
```

Html as below:

```
<div id="personal-information">
    <input data-bind="value: firstName" type="text" >
    <input data-bind="value: lastName" type="text" >
</div>
<div id="contact-information">
    <input data-bind="value: homePhone" type="text" >
    <input data-bind="value: mobile" type="text" >
</div>
<div id="address-information">
    <input data-bind="value: city" type="text" >
    <input data-bind="value: street" type="text" >
</div>
```

The default value for these input fields is fetched from 3 different tables in the database. I want to edit these values and update data in those tables.

If I change a value of inputs in PersonViewModel only, I want to make an ajax request that will call update query for person table only.
And same for address and contact ViewModel. I know how to make ajax request.

But my problem is: Using knockoutJs, how can I know that only those particular ViewModels that are updated so that I can leave the rest at it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each View Model you could create a method to which other observables can subscribe to. For instance, for the PersonViewModel:

```
function PersonViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("@Model.FirstName");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("@Model.LastName");

    this.updatePerson = function () { /* AJAX */ };

    // subscriptions
    this.firstName.subscribe(this.updatePerson);
    this.lastName.subscribe(this.updatePerson);
 }
```

So whenever the value of **firstName** or **lastName** changes the **updatePerson** method will be triggered.

The same idea for the other view models

```
function ContactViewModel() {
    this.homePhone = ko.observable("@Model.HomePhone");
    this.mobile = ko.observable("@Model.Mobile");

    this.updateContact = function () { /* AJAX */ };

    // subscriptions
    this.homePhone.subscribe(this.updateContact);
    this.mobile.subscribe(this.updateContact);
}

function AddressViewModel() {
    this.city = ko.observable("@Model.City");
    this.street = ko.observable("@Model.Street");

    this.updateAddress = function () { /* AJAX */ };

    // subscriptions
    this.city.subscribe(this.updateAddress);
    this.street.subscribe(this.updateAddress);
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks Rafael. Works for what i want to do. But is there a way to do it without calling subscribe(this.update...) for each of the observables? A simple tweak to handle it all by itself rather than same code for each of the observables is what i am looking for now.

Comment: You could use a computed observable that 'listens' for changes in several other observables and then  subscribe only this computed observable to the update method -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/9278782/1942895

Comment: Now i've found that this work only with <input>, when i use a <select>(Dropdown) it will call update, even on page load. Also, the content for my dropdown is supplied from mvc model containing list of selectListitems. Can you help? Thanks