# Knockout Computed Observable Only Recognizes One Observable

Tags: knockout.js

**Background:** I am working on a webpage using Knockout 3.4.0. On the page, I use a computed observable to calculate the cost of a fee (in dollars). The fee can either be a percentage or a flat rate, and this percentage/flat rate information can be inserted into one of two textboxes. I use radio buttons and jQuery for the user to select which text box is active, as the user can only pick percentage **or** flat rate. I am also loading the view model using JSON and ko.mapping, but that doesn't seem to be the issue here. I should also mention that the client's target browser is IE11 or Edge.

**Issue:** The computed observable does not seem to be subscribing to changes in the flat rate text box. When I run the application on my localhost (the application itself is .NET MVC), the flat rate text box responds once. When I moved the code to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lof38662/4/) for this write up, the box does not respond at all. Here is the observable:

```
self.serviceFeeComputed= ko.computed(function () {
    if (self.ServiceFee.Percentage() !== null 
        && self.ServiceFee.Percentage() !== 0) {
            return self.Amount() * (self.ServiceFee.Percentage() / 100);
    } else {
        return self.ServiceFee.FlatRate();
    }
});
```

**Attempts at Resolution:** I've spent around 6 - 8 hours over the last two weeks trying to fix this issue. Here are some of the things I've tried:

1. I've defined the view model in different fashions, such as a function, or JavaScript object: `var viewModel = { ... }`
2. I've turned ServiceFee into an observable - no results, so I changed back.
3. I've copied the Percentage textbox over the Flat Rate text box to ensure that the other attributes were the same.
4. I've switched from `ko.computed()` to `ko.pureComputed()`
5. I've switched the order in which the conditional statement operates, so that I check `self.ServiceFee.FlatRate()` first. This causes the flat rate textbox to update the fee, but not the percentage. Keying off this fact, I did a search and found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278497/knockoutjs-subscribe-to-multiple-observables-with-same-callback-action), but upon calling both observables in the computed, I didn't get a working result. I also tried different variations of this solution, such as creating variables using the observables, or adding them together. Regardless of what I do, it seems that the first variable examined in the conditional statement is the one that receives the subscription.

   ```
   self.serviceFeeComputed = ko.computed(function () {
       self.ServiceFee.Percentage();
       self.ServiceFee.FlatRate();
       if (self.ServiceFee.Percentage() !== null && self.ServiceFee.Percentage() !== 0) {
           return self.Amount() * (self.ServiceFee.Percentage() / 100);
       } else {
           return self.ServiceFee.FlatRate();
       }
   });
   ```

**Ideal Resolution:** I'd like for both the text boxes to update the computed observable, regardless of how many times the user switches back and forth between percentage and flat rate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason that causes `the box does not respond at all` is you've made a typo mistake at your HTML binding. `text: serviceFeeCompued` need to be fixed to `text: serviceFeeComputed`

Comment: Also, could you explain what behavior that you want the text box to have from the User's view? I'm not sure that I understand your purpose.

Comment: You're over complicating this for yourself by doing too much with jQuery. You should be able to accomplish everything you need, including enabling/disabling the inputs, with knockout.

Comment: @trgiangvp3 - Hi, thanks for noticing my typo. I've added that tag so that we can see the serviceFeeComputed on the page. Unfortunately, fixing the typo has no effect on the original issue though. As far as purpose, I want the text boxes to remove a portion from the Contract total. In my example, I initialize Amount to 1000. If someone enters a '1' in the percent box, 1% should be subtracted from the Amount and that should be displayed in the Contract Cost box as 990. If someone enters a '1' in the flat rate box, 1 should be subtracted from the amount and that should be displayed as 999.

Comment: @Drummad - Thanks for the feedback. I'll look into switching the jQuery functionality to use Knockout. However, removing the jQuery altogether and enabling both text boxes does not resolve this issue, as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lof38662/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem came from two things:

1. As [Drummad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3443313/drummad) has
   pointed out in his comment, **you're over complicating things by
   wrongly combining jQuery with KO**
2. You've got a **mistake in determining the condition of when to use Percent and when to use Flatrate**

I have fixed your code at [CodePen](https://codepen.io/trgiangvp3/pen/qpEOge)

```js
// You will not need jQuery at all, KO is enough
// You need a boolean property to determine if the Flatrate or the Percentage is used
self.ServiceFee = {
  Percentage: ko.observable(),
  FlatRate: ko.observable(),
  IsPercentage: ko.observable(true) // Add this property to ServiceFee
};

self.serviceFeeComputed = ko.computed(function() {
  //if (self.ServiceFee.Percentage() !== null && self.ServiceFee.Percentage() !== 0) {
  if (self.ServiceFee.IsPercentage()) { // this is the right condition
    return self.Amount() * (self.ServiceFee.Percentage() / 100);
  } else {
    return self.ServiceFee.FlatRate();
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- You will not need jQuery at all, KO is enough -->
<!-- You need a boolean property to determine if the Flatrate or the Percentage is used -->

<label class="radio-inline col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1">
  <input name="Test" type="radio" data-bind="checkedValue: true, checked: ServiceFee.IsPercentage" />
  <!-- <input type="radio" name="percentageOrFlatRate" value="percentage" /> -->
</label>
... other code ...
<input class="form-control"
  data-bind="textInput: ServiceFee.Percentage, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', enable: ServiceFee.IsPercentage"
  data-value="percentage" id="ServiceFee_Percentage" name="ServiceFee.Percentage"
  placeholder="0.00" type="number" value="" />

... other code ...

<label class="radio-inline  col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1">
  <input name="Test" type="radio" data-bind="checkedValue: false, checked: ServiceFee.IsPercentage" />
  <!-- <input type="radio" name="percentageOrFlatRate" value="flatRate" /> -->
</label>
... other code ...
<input class="form-control"
  data-bind="textInput: ServiceFee.FlatRate, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', disable: ServiceFee.IsPercentage"
  data-value="flatRate" id="ServiceFee_Percentage" name="ServiceFee.Percentage"
  placeholder="0.00" type="number" value="" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I was able to integrate much of it into my solution, modifying it for use with both adding new data and editing pre-existing data. I'm still interested in knowing the underlying cause so that I can better understand the mechanics of KO. For computed observables, does KO only subscribe to the first observable in the function?

Comment: No, I don't think so. As you can see in the CodePen I've posted above, inside the serviceFeeComputed function, there are 3 observable variables which you can change from the UI and they work well. But, I don't know KO well enough to explain why your computed function not to be called when the Flatrate changed.

Comment: The problem was entirely in the logic of your computed. You had `self.ServiceFee.Percentage() !== null && self.ServiceFee.Percentage() !== 0` but `Percentage` would never be either of those values because input values are strings, not numbers. You could change it to `self.ServiceFee.Percentage() !== null && self.ServiceFee.Percentage() != 0` (`!==` to `!=`) to match a string value, but @trgiangvp3's solution is probably better.

Comment: @MichaelBest I have created another jsfiddle base on floppsb's one to find out why his computed not get called https://jsfiddle.net/trgiangvp3/dks24cxt/ When I edit the Percentage textbox, the alert is shown but nothing happens when I edit the Flatrate textbox. I can't understand why. Could you explain the case?

Comment: `Percentage` actually starts off as `undefined`, so the computed either needs to check for that or use something like `if (self.ServiceFee.Percentage()) ...`.

Comment: I understand that the condition in the if statement is wrong. But I mentioned something else. When I edit the Percentage textbox, KO knows the change and updates model value, KO also triggered the computed function and you see the alert is fired. When I edit the Flatrate textbox, KO still knows the change and updates model value but the computed not even get called. That's what I don't understand.

Comment: If you change the percentage value to `0`, you will see that updating the flat rate value will update the computed. But if the percentage value is non-zero, the computed only uses that value and doesn't read the flat rate value.

Comment: @MichaelBest Thank you very much. So the dependency chain mechanism is more complicated than I used to think.

Comment: The description at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-dependency-tracking.html is pretty good.